# Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

Suppose that we have two independent random variables, $x$ and $n$. They are both normally distributed: $x \sim N(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$, $n \sim N(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$.

Let:
$$y = x + ln(1 + e^{(n-x)})$$

If somehow we know the approximation of the mean and variance of $ln(1 + e^{(n-x)})$ is $\mu_3$ and $\sigma_3^2$, respectively. (This information is provided if you cannot solve this question analytically.)

The question is to calculate this conditional expectation:
$$E(x|y=y_i)$$

The difficulty lies in that $ln(1 + e^{(n-x)})$ is not normally distributed, otherwise an approximate solution is easy to be got.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Rewrite as $e^{y-x}=1+e^{n-x}\Rightarrow e^x=e^y-e^n\Rightarrow x=y\log(1-e^{n-y})$.

Comment: @A.S. Thank you very much.